# failed to parse using R package haven read_sas

Tags: r, sas, r-haven

I'm importing a sas data file (.**sas7bdat**) and its corresponding formats (in R language called "*labels*") with a (.**sas7bcat**) file to R using haven's package command "**read_sas**". Importing the sas file on its own work just fine. However, when I try to import it with the formats using the following code import the formats file **sas7bcat** I get the following error message :

```r
pri <- read_sas (path = "Datasets/pri.sas7bdat",
                 path.cat = "Datasets/formats.sas7bcat")
```

> Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding, catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding,
> Failed to parse .../formats.sas7bcat: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.

I don't have any idea where the problem lies. I have almost 250 variables on the SAS file and they all have both labels and formats (in SAS terminology).

I have read everything related to this question on stack overflow. I believe that the problem probably lies with the formats file itself, but I can't figure out what's the problem.

I'm using the latest version of Haven 2.3.1 : and R v. 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) using RStudio v.1.3.1093 on Windows 10.

[This link has the SAS code for the formats](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rre72wqjapzjucb/SAS%20Formats.txt?dl=0)

[This link has the .sas7bcat library](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ccusajvgavpn9z/formats.sas7bcat?dl=0)

Comment: What version of R itself is your R studio session using?  The number you have provided is just for the R studio interface, not the actual R application that R studio is using to execute the R code.

Comment: v.4.0.3, I will update the question

Comment: Do you know if any of the formats are picture formats or multi-level formats or other complex SAS formats?

Comment: @Tom I've checked and I'm not quite sure. I think there are none. However, I have attached the SAS code for the formats and the sas7bcat library to this question.

Comment: I see some non-7bit ASCII codes in the text `Mundhöhle`. What encoding did you use when creating the format catalog?

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure. Those were German special letters. I have changed them all to English letters now. It still however does not work. I updated the SAS code for formats and the library after editing.

Comment: Do you have access to SAS? If so, did you already try a minimal version of the import? In general, I believe it is best to post the code completely and not just a link pointing to it.

Answer (score 1):

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
#> Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] haven_2.3.1
```

I created a database `class` in SAS as:

```
data temp.class;
  set sashelp.class;
  if sex = "M" then sexnum = 1; else sexnum = 2;
  format sexnum sexfmt.;
run;
```

Note that your syntax doesn't work for me:

```r
haven::read_sas (path = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", 
                 path.cat = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat")
#> Error in read_sas(path = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", path.cat = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat") : 
#>   unused arguments (path = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", path.cat = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat")
```

Then I used the following syntax and I got the same message as you:

```r
haven::read_sas (data_file = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", 
                 catalog_file = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat")
#> Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding, catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding,  : 
#>   Failed to parse D:/temp/formats.sas7bcat: Invalid file, or file has unsupported features.
```

or if `language for message` is set to `fr`:

```r
haven::read_sas (data_file = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", 
                 catalog_file = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat")
#> Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding, catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding,  : 
#>   Failed to parse D:/temp/formats.sas7bcat: Unable to allocate memory.
```

It's due to the format `rekof` which has no value. It's OK removing it :

```r
haven::read_sas (data_file = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", 
                 catalog_file = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat")
#> # A tibble: 19 x 6
#>    Name    Sex     Age Height Weight     sexnum
#>    <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl+lbl>
#>  1 Alfred  M        14   69    112.  1 [Male]  
#>  2 Alice   F        13   56.5   84   2 [Female]
#>  3 Barbara F        13   65.3   98   2 [Female]
#>  4 Carol   F        14   62.8  102.  2 [Female]
#>  5 Henry   M        14   63.5  102.  1 [Male]  
#>  6 James   M        12   57.3   83   1 [Male]  
#>  7 Jane    F        12   59.8   84.5 2 [Female]
#>  8 Janet   F        15   62.5  112.  2 [Female]
#>  9 Jeffrey M        13   62.5   84   1 [Male]  
#> 10 John    M        12   59     99.5 1 [Male]  
#> 11 Joyce   F        11   51.3   50.5 2 [Female]
#> 12 Judy    F        14   64.3   90   2 [Female]
#> 13 Louise  F        12   56.3   77   2 [Female]
#> 14 Mary    F        15   66.5  112   2 [Female]
#> 15 Philip  M        16   72    150   1 [Male]  
#> 16 Robert  M        12   64.8  128   1 [Male]  
#> 17 Ronald  M        15   67    133   1 [Male]  
#> 18 Thomas  M        11   57.5   85   1 [Male]  
#> 19 William M        15   66.5  112   1 [Male]
```

To remove the format `rekof`, you can either:

- delete the formats catalog
- comment the line as `/* value rekof ; */`
- regenerate the formats catalog (execute the `proc format`)

or use the following SAS code:

```
proc catalog catalog=lcoc.formats; 
  delete rekof (et=format);
run;
```

---

***Minimal example producing the error***

In SAS

```
libname temp "d:/temp";
option fmtsearch=(temp);

proc format lib=temp;
  value test;
run;

data temp.class;
  set sashelp.class;
run;
```

In R

```r
haven::read_sas (data_file = "d:/temp/class.sas7bdat", 
                 catalog_file = "d:/temp/formats.sas7bcat")
#> Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding, catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding,  : 
#>   Failed to parse D:/temp/formats.sas7bcat: Unable to allocate memory.
```

Regards,

Comment: How do you remove the format `rekof`? and what is it exactly?

Comment: Does it always fail if the do nothing format is in the format catalog?  Or does the format have to be used in the dataset being converted to trigger the error?

Comment: I updated my message to explain how do you remove the format rekof. @Tom: The format has not to be used in the dataset being converted to trigger the error. It always fails if the do nothing format is in the formats catalog. I added a minimal example producing the error.